# Jasper - Conditional frame and resize of band

Tags: jasper-reports, column-header-band

I've a `columnHeader` band which contains two frames.

The first frame must be visible if a parameter is `TRUE`, the second frame must be visible if the same parameter is `FALSE`.

So I want to show only one frame.

I've put two frames sequentially. The visibility is OK but when I show the first frame remains a blank space between it and detail band (because the second frame has been hidden but occupy the space).

How can I remove this space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At property of frame on bookmark "Appearence" set checkbox "Remove line when blank".

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your solution. See you later.

Comment: I'm donkey newbie about Jasper. Thank you very much. Now it's OK!

Comment: i tried with "Remove line when blank" checked ,but still it is taking white space